# How do I discuss amendments to the Java Virtual Machine Specification?

Tags: java, jvm, specifications

I have some improvements to suggest to the Java Virtual Machine Specification authors (I detected some slight ambiguities in the specification). Where should amendments to the JVMS be proposed and discussed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [The Java® Virtual Machine Specification Java SE 9 Edition, section Feedback](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se9/html/jvms-1.html#jvms-1.5):

> Readers are invited to report technical errors and ambiguities in *The
>   Java® Virtual Machine Specification* to
>   `jls-jvms-spec-comments@openjdk.java.net`.
>
> Questions concerning the generation and manipulation of class files by
>   `javac` (the reference compiler for the Java programming language) may
>   be sent to `compiler-dev@openjdk.java.net`.

Comment: Thanks, I entirely missed the Feedback section!